# Building Iac scanning pipeline in gitlab encountered problems

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use Infrastructure as Code (IaC) Scanning scans my IaC configuration files for known vulnerabilities. Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/iac_scanning/. However, I encountered the system problem in the pipeline.

```
[DEBU] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:29Z] [/go/pkg/mod/gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/command@v1.9.2/run.go:256] ▶ SAST_EXCLUDED_PATHS=spec,test,tests,tmp39
[INFO] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:29Z] [/go/pkg/mod/gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/command@v1.9.2/run.go:131] ▶ Detecting project
[INFO] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:29Z] [/go/pkg/mod/gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/command@v1.9.2/run.go:153] ▶ Analyzer will attempt to analyze all projects in the repository41
[INFO] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:29Z] [/go/pkg/mod/gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/command@v1.9.2/run.go:165] ▶ Running analyzer42
[DEBU] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:29Z] [/go/src/app/analyze.go:48] ▶ custom rulesets not enabled
[INFO] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:29Z] [/go/src/app/analyze.go:67] ▶ path /builds/leo/tcf
[ERRO] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:38Z] [/go/src/app/analyze.go:87] ▶ Encountered a system problem; status code: 2, error: exit status 2, detail:
[FATA] [kics] [2022-11-11T03:55:38Z] [/go/src/app/main.go:30] ▶ kics scanner failure: exit status 2
Uploading artifacts for failed job00:0048Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: gl-sast-report.json: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables00:0154ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I can't find relevant information about the errors. How can I solve the errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own config, independent of the GitLab template.

**gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
  image:
    name: checkmarx/kics:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - kics scan -q /app/bin/assets/queries -p ${PWD} --ignore-on-exit all --report-formats glsast -o ${PWD} --output-name kics-results 
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-kics-results.json
    when: always
```